# Adjust code to allow using ACF repeater field for image comparison slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, repeater, acfpro

I am trying to build a dynamic image comparison slider that works with ACF repeater field. I used the html, css and js from this blog post: https://dev.to/shantanu_jana/image-comparison-slider-using-html-css-and-javascript-3cff

And it works as I need it, besides that it is not working with ACF repeater (or in general having multiple comparison sliders on one page, which is what I need)

I suppose it's because of the IDs that are needed for the JS, but I don't have enough experience to adjust the code to have it working. Can someone help? Or is it not possible?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <img src="<?php echo get_field( 'slider_1' ); ?>">

  <img id="my-img" src="<?php echo get_field( 'slider_2' ); ?>">

  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="slider" oninput="slide()">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    background: #d1ebec;
    place-items: center;
}


.container{
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid #bfc0c1;
    box-shadow:-3px 5px 15px #000;

}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#my-img{
    clip-path: polygon(0 0 , 50% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
}


#slider{
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: calc( 100% + 40px);
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    background: url("slider-icon.svg"),
    rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    border: 4px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: contain;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
function slide(){
    let slideValue = document.getElementById("slider").value;

    document.getElementById("my-img").style.clipPath = "polygon(0 0," + slideValue + "% 0," + slideValue + "% 100%, 0 100%)";

    console.log("polygon(0 0," + slideValue + "% 0," + slideValue + "% 100%, 0 100%)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so you can use classes and `document.querySelectorAll()`

you can select all elements you want to select dude

```js
let sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.my-img').value;
  sliders.forEach(item => {
    item.style.clipPath = 
      "polygon(0 0," + slideValue + "% 0," + slideValue + "% 100%, 0 100%)";

})
```

and then change the id :`id="my-img"` to class :`class="my-img"`

then use your ACF repeater

(as you said ids must be unique and when you use repeater you make many elements with same id which is bad and you most not to do )

Comment: don't forget to update id in style sheet

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it is not working for me. In the html I changed the id="my-img" to class="my-img" and also changed that in the stylesheet. In the js file, I replaced the document.getElementById("my-img") row with your code, but then the slider doesn't work anymore. You can still drag the handle left + right, but it doesn't reveal the images anymore

Comment: @JanaLux   also do you used forEach?

Comment: yes, I copied the code from you exactly how it is, including the forEach